# Integral with trigonometric subtitution.

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

$\int\frac1{e^x\sqrt{4+e^{2x}}}dx$

In my textbook the solution of this integral says that $u=e^x$ and $du=e^xdx$ is the substitution to go, and then transforms the integer in this

$\int\frac1{u\sqrt{4+u^{2x}}}du$

but according to my knowledge, it should be like this

$\int\frac1{u^{2}\sqrt{4+u^{2x}}}du$

because $\frac{du}{u}=dx$, so you have $\int\frac1{u\sqrt{4+u^{2x}}}*\frac{du}{u}$

did i understand wrong the substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be $\int{du\over{u^2\sqrt{4+u^2}}}$ with that substitution. Replace $dx$ with $du\over{e^x}$ and $e^{2x}$ with $u^2$

The x is substituted out when $e^{2x}$ is substituted by  $u^2$.